¿alguien sabe como puedo guardar un documento dentro de otro docmento estoy usando node js y mongo db?
tengo el siguiente codigo que al iniciar sesion se guarda el object id del cliente pero quisiera que se guardaran los campos del cliente como su Nombre y Email
pero solo se guarda el id he estado intentado pero no logro conseguirlo
export const login = async (req, res) => {
const { Email, Password } = req.body;
try {
    const userFound = await User.findOne({ Email });
    
    const iniciosDeSesion = new IniciosDeSesion({
        ip: req.ip,
        usuario: userFound._id, // Guardar el _id del usuario
        motivo: "Inicio de sesion"
    });

    if (!userFound) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Usuario no encontrado" });
    
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(Password, userFound.Password);

    if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Contraseña incorrecta" });

    const token = await createAccessToken({ id: userFound._id });
    console.log(token);

    res.cookie('token', token);

    // Envía la respuesta con los datos del usuario y el mensaje de inicio de sesión exitoso
    res.status(200).json({
        id: userFound._id,
        Nombre: userFound.Nombre,
        Email: userFound.Email,
        createdAt: userFound.createdAt,
        updatedAt: userFound.updatedAt,
        message: 'Inicio de sesión exitoso'
    });

    // Guarda el registro de inicio de sesión
    await iniciosDeSesion.save();

} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
}

};
